# How to deal with dynamic JSON data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

So lets say I have an Angular Service that is responsible for consuming a RESTful Web Service. The Service needs to interact with more than one API, depending on the request. Both APIs return similar data but the returned JSON is formatted differently which makes binding difficult.

As an example, API1 may return:

```
{"employees":[
   {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
   {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
   {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

where as API2 may return:

```
{"employees":[
   {"lstNme":"Doe", "fstNme":"John"},
   {"lstNme":"Smith", "fstNme":"Anna"},
   {"lstNme":"Jones", "fstNme":"Peter"}
]}
```

What would be the best way to manage the differing structures of the API returns?

Comment: Have an abstraction layer in between that changes the data to 1 unified format.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: You would have a service in between your controller in the data, probably a .factory (so you can use it as a model) that makes the api calls and then changes the data to however you want it to look.

Comment: Yes I get what you are saying, but how would I change the data?

Comment: You would create a model. The part of the model that interprets last/first name would also check for the lstNme/fstNme stuff and put it in the same place in the model as the initial api call example.